# Who caused first collapse of wave function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, measurement-problem, wavefunction-collapse

With my wife we discuss a quantum theory and wonder whether a wave function could collapse without an observer - meaning a human/or any other living beings.

If so we could make a conclusion that there would be no matter/gravity/atoms until any living beings exist. But how would be a living being created?

In other words - how is defined the observer that can cause collapse of a wave function? Must it be a human/living being?

Comment: For "observer" in the abstract sense I would suggest "any interaction between things" is how I think of it.  No conscious entity required.

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine The issue with this is that if you allow any interaction between things to collapse a wave function, we would never have any superpositions, as there are constantly interactions going on. We know this not to be the case. The second issue is that without a measurement being done, the basis in which to collapse to is undefined. Do you want to get rid of your superpositions in the position basis? In the momentum basis? You can't do both.

Comment: In epistemic interpretations of QM, the wave function is not a property of the system but a representation of an agent's (read: scientist's) knowledge of the system, or at least a way to formalize the probabilities of outcomes of experiments. From that perspective, there's nothing wrong with no collapse occurring when then there is no human. In other words, the wave function isn't "what-the-universe-is-made-of". It's just a description of how quantum systems *behave*.

Comment: @doublefelix I don't really consider wavefunction collapse as a useful concept.  I don't really find any interpretation of quantum theory particularly useful.  I'd be closest to the [Ensemble interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_interpretation) but I'm not particularly dogmatic about interpretations.  I think collapsing wavefunctions is a great way to confuse students and not much else, rather like Schrodinger's Cat.  Deep issues may (or may not ?) hang on interpretations but they're beyond my pay scale, I guess. :-)

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine Without collapse, how do you predict that when starting with a state $|\psi \rangle$ and doing two spin measurements separated by 3 seconds, wherein the first measurement gave spin up, the probability of getting spin down on the second measurement is $|\langle \downarrow |e^{-i(3)H/\hbar}|\uparrow \rangle \langle \uparrow |\psi \rangle|^2$? The intermediate wavefunction collapse affects the results. You won't get the same probability without it. Thus it is not just useful but indispensable unless you want to give up experimental predictability.

Comment: Note that the expression above should have a normalization factor $1/|\langle \uparrow |\psi \rangle|$ inside the $|\cdot |^2$ because after projecting to collapse, you need to renormalize. But it was getting messy so rather not add it all in there in one big jumble.

Comment: That is a circular argument. If the only time evolution one needs to consider is still just the restriction of the universe's Hamiltonian to the one that acts on $\left | \psi \right >$ then you have assumed collapse. The way to not assume it is to realize that the spin system above does not have its own probability distribution anymore. It has a joint distribution with the measuring device which has become highly correlated.

Answer (score 3):

Your question, stated rhetorically, is itself the measurement problem. John Bell said it in a really nice way:

> "What exactly qualifies some physical systems to play the role of 'measurer'? Was the wavefunction of the world waiting to jump for thousands of millions of years until a single-celled living creature appeared? Or did it have to wait a little longer, for some better qualified system... with a PhD?"

The quote is from [his 1990 article](https://www.tau.ac.il/%7Equantum/Vaidman/IQM/BellAM.pdf) in *Physics Today*.

As such, there is no consensus about what the solution is, thus one could call it unsolved, though I should mention that there are solution(s) proposed. One thing that is largely agreed upon, though, is that this "cut" should not be taken so seriously, in the sense that something is not right about choosing a moment to do a discontinuous chopping of the wavefunction, or choosing privileged physical systems that get to be called "observers". Professors will internally not take this seriously, but still teach the traditional framework for the feeling that they lack a better option, and it because is in textbooks (for the same reasons).

Physicists loosely prefer "just Schrödinger evolution" but nonetheless do not agree on a replacement for the measurement postulates that we do in fact need to make predictions for experiment. For example, if you don't collapse the wave function, it cannot predict that the next measurement will yield one particular result with 100% certainty.

I have explored a number of solutions and the only one that, to me, has been satisfactory, is that of Bohmian Mechanics. I don't have a great video source to explain how it works... but [this talk on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yr5yGxJg2X0) does go over it if you'd like to know more.